# Backpropagation in Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow.js

I am making an RNN for sentiment classification while using a many to one structure. In order to make my RNN be able to run within an HTML file.

To make the question short and simple:

> What is the Tensorflow.js equivalent of Tensorflow's (the python
> version) `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By gradient descent, you probably would prefer stochastic gradient descent (sampling random batches) and it would look like:

```
tf.train.stg(learningRate).minimize(loss)
```

Read more here: https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.train.Optimizer.minimize